# Assign capabilities for new role in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, roles, wordpress-capabilities

I am working on woocommerce plugin. In plugin, I created a new role `Franchiser`. When I install the plugin and go to `New User` screen it shows me my created role in dropdown.

Now I want to give capabilities for this new role and has access just these screens on admin panel:

```
- Dashboard
- Woocommerce
    - View Orders List
    - View Order Details
- Products
- Profile
```

> I tried these capabilities but it shows a lot of screens:

```
'level_9' => true,
'level_8' => true,
'level_7' => true,
'level_6' => true,
'level_5' => true,
'level_4' => true,
'level_3' => true,
'level_2' => true,
'level_1' => true,
'level_0' => true,
'read' => true,
'read_private_posts' => true,
'edit_posts' => true,
'edit_published_posts' => true,
'edit_private_posts' => true,
'edit_others_posts' => true,
'publish_posts' => true,
'delete_posts' => true,
'delete_private_posts' => true,
'delete_published_posts' => true,
'delete_others_posts' => true,
'manage_categories' => true,
'upload_files' => true,
```

So what kind of capabilities I gave to my new role so user can access only above mentioned screens in admin panel.

Hope you understand my question.

Comment: There's a list of all core capabilities here https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/roles-and-capabilities/ plugins like WooCommerce might define more capabilities or use role checks, for the best granular control you can take a look at the `map_meta_caps` filter.